# Prove that $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ both are continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> For a $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a point $x_0$ in $D$, define $A=\{x\in D\vert x\geq x_0\}$ and $B=\{x\in D\vert x\leq x_0\}$. Prove that $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ both are continuous at $x_0$.

---

Since $A$, $B$ are subsets of $D$ and for any point $x_0$ in $D$,  $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0$; hence $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ both are continuous at $x_0$.

Conversely, for any point $x_0$ in $D$, we have $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ both are continuous at $x_0$ which mean $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_o^{+}} f(x)=x_0\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_o^{-}} f(x)=x_0$$

By the uniqueness of limit, we have $x\in D$ that can give us $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_o} f(x)=x_0$; hence $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0$.

---

Can anyone check my solution? I am not sure that I have showed enough information. And does this theorem always true? Such as $ f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2\,\,\,\text{if $x\geq 0$}\\-x\,\,\,\text{if $x< 0$} \end{cases}$, we can let $x_0=0$ and then apply this theorem, but if $x_0\neq 0$,we can't get the same limit if we define $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\vert x\geq 0\}$ and $B=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\vert x\leq 0\}$ or I misunderstand this theorem. Thanks

Comment: At the end you defined $A$ and $B$ wrong. You should have put $x\geq x_0$ and $x\leq x_0$. Now what's really $f:B\to\mathbb R$ if $x_0> 0$?

Comment: @Heimdall That would be $f(x_0^2)$

Comment: $f:A\to\mathbb R$ is simply $x^2$. But on$B$ it's $-x$ for $x<0$ and $x^2$ for $0\leq x\leq x_0$. So what's the limit on each side of $x_0$?

Comment: @Heimdall that should be $x_0$

Comment: Actually, the limits in definitions are wrong. $x\to x_0$, $f(x)\to f(x_0)$ (not as you put it: $f(x)\to x_0$)